# Proof explanation related to multinomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

Let $\mathbf{X}= (X_1,\cdots,X_d)$ be a $d$-variables and $\mathbf{G}(n,d)$ denotes the set of all functions from $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ into  $\{1,\cdots,d\}$.

> If the variables $X_k$ are commuting i.e. $X_iX_j=X_jX_i$ for all $i,j\in \{1,\cdots,d\}$, why
>   $$\sum_{g\in \mathbf{G}(n,d)} \mathbf{X}_g=\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|=n,\\\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d}}\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\mathbf{X}}^{\alpha}?$$
>   where 
>    $\mathbf{X}_g:=\prod_{i=1}^dX_{g(i)}$, for $g\in \mathbf{G}(n,d)$. Also $|\alpha|=\sum_{j=1}^d|\alpha_j|$. Further, we write $\alpha!: =\prod_{i=1}^d\alpha_i!$ and $\mathbf{X}^\alpha:=\prod_{i=1}^dX_i^{\alpha_i}$.

The following proof is inspired from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632761/proof-verification-why-this-formula-holds), however I don't understand the idea very well because I think, we should prove that
$$\left\{{\bf X}_{g}\,;\;g\in {\bf \large G}(n,d) \right\}=\left\{\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\bf X}^{\alpha}\,;\;|\alpha|=n \right\}.$$
I hope also to understand the formula in the case when $d=3$ that is $\mathbf{X}= (X_1,X_2,X_3)$.

**Proof:** For some chosen $g$, set $\alpha_k:=|\{j\in\{1,\cdots,n\};\;g(j)=k\}|$, where the bars $|\,|$ means "cardinality of the set". In other words: $\alpha_k=|g^{-1}(\{k\})|$, the cardinality of the fiber of $k$ for some chosen $g$.

And because $X_iX_j=X_jX_i$ for all $i,j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ then $\mathbf{X}_g=\mathbf{X}^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d$ such that $|\alpha|=n$.

But for each $\alpha$ there are $\binom{n}{\alpha}$ distinct $g$ such that $\mathbf{X}_g=\mathbf{X}^\alpha$ because $X_iX_j=X_jX_i$ for all $i,j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$, that is there are $\binom{n}\alpha$ different ways to order the list $g(1),g(2),\cdots, g(n)$ for some chosen $g$.

**Remark:**  I ask this question because I want to understand the following problem related to **operator theory**.

For a given ${\bf A}=(A_1,\cdots,A_d) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^d$ which is **not commuting**, the joint spectral radius of ${\bf A}$ is defined by
$$r({\bf A })= \inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\bigg(\bigg\|\sum_{g\in {\bf \large G}(n,d)} {\bf A}_g^* {\bf A}_{g}\bigg\|^{\frac{1}{2n}} \bigg).
$$
However, I don't understand why  if ${\bf A}$ is **commuting**, then
$$r({\bf A}) = \inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{|\alpha|=n}\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{{\bf A}^*}^{\alpha}{\bf A}^{\alpha}\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}}?$$

Comment: The LHS is just $\left(X_1 + \cdots + X_d\right)^n$, so you're trying to prove the multinomial formula. Myriad places where this is done.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you for your comment. My question is not to show the multinomial formula.

Comment: I think, as the close-voters suggested, that you are going to have to provide more context if you are to obtain a useful answer to your question. In particular, how does your question relate to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2641859/3736), from which the proof you give seems to have been derived? Would a different proof do just as well? Where are you getting stuck? In fact I don't see an actual question in your post.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thank you for your comment. Please see my edit.

Comment: As @darijgrinberg said, the assertion in the block quote is the multinonomial expansion, so I'm still not sure why you say that your question is not to show the multinomial formula.  The equation $$\left\{{\bf X}_{g}\,;\;g\in {\bf \large G}(n,d) \right\}=\left\{\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\bf X}^{\alpha}\,;\;|\alpha|=n \right\}$$ can't hold since the set on the left has $d^n$ members, while the set on the right has $\binom{d+n-1}{d-1}$ members.  In the binomial case, there are $2^n$ functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,2\}$ but only $n+1$ ways to write $n$ as the sum of two non-negative integers.

Comment: So when $n=3$, $(1,2,3)$ can map to $(1,1,1)$, $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$, $(1,2,2)$, $(2,1,1)$, $(2,1,2)$, $(2,2,1)$, and $(2,2,2)$, but the only ways to write $3$ as the sum of two non-negative integers are $0+3$, $1+2$, $2+1$, $3+0$.  In the sum, $0+3$ is associated with the map to $(2,2,2)$; $1+2$ is associated with three maps: the one to $(1,2,2)$, the one to $(2,1,2)$, and the one to $(2,2,1)$.

Comment: Yes.  This is just the rule for expanding a product of polynomials.  For intuition, try a small example, such as $d=2$, $n=3$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However I think there exists a problem in the given answer. Please see it.

Comment: What problem?  Are you referring to the question of whether $\alpha$ depends on $g$ or is arbitrary?  This seems to be a repeated sticking point.

Comment: Where is $\alpha$ arbitrary?  Any particular $g$ will correspond to a **particular** $\alpha$.  And every $\alpha$ (whose elements add to $n$) corresponds to at least one $g$.  (There is always the $g$ such that $g(1)\le g(2)\le g(3)\le\ldots$.  For example, if $d=2$, $n=3$, and $\alpha=(2,1)$ then you can pick $g$ so that $g(1)=g(2)=1$ and $g(3)=2$, but this is not the only choice.)  So **every** $\alpha$ (whose elements add to $n$) needs to be included in the summation, and all that remains is to find the coefficient, which is the number of $g$s that correspond to a given $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for your expalnation. I understand in his answer that he takes $\alpha$ arbitrary. Also If ${\bf T}=(T_1,...,T_d) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^d$. $\mathbf{T}^\alpha$ is defined to be $T_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots T_d^{\alpha_d}$.

Please, when we write $\mathbf{T}^\alpha$, it is necessary to assume that $T_iT_j=T_iT_j$ for all $i,j\in 1,\cdots,d$? Because if $d=2$ and $\alpha=(2,3)$, then we can always write  $\mathbf{T}^\alpha=T_1^2T_2^3$ even if $T_1$ doen't commute with $T_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88462/discussion-between-will-orrick-and-schuler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum
$$\sum_{g\in \mathbf{G}(n,d)} \mathbf{X}_g
$$
is what you get when you expand a multinomial ($d$-nomial) raised to the $n^\text{th}$ power without assuming commutativity.

The sum that appears in your application doesn't arise from the expansion of a power, but is otherwise similar.  I think the smallest non-trivial case ($d=2$, $n=2$) illustrates what needs to be understood.  On the left we have a sum
$$
\sum_{g\in {\bf \large G}(n,d)} {\bf A}_g^* {\bf A}_{g}=A_1^*A_1^*A_1A_1
+A_1^*A_2^*A_1A_2
+A_2^*A_1^*A_2A_1
+A_2^*A_2^*A_2A_2,
$$ 
in which the order of the operators in each product (in both the left half of the product, containing the operators $A_i*$, and in the right half, containing the operators $A_i$) is not necessarily lexicographic.  That is, $A_2$ sometimes occurs to the left of $A_1$ (and $A_2^*$ to the left of $A_1^*$). On the right we have a sum
$$
\sum_{|\alpha|=n}\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{{\bf A}^*}^{\alpha}{\bf A}^{\alpha}=\frac{2!}{2!\,0!}A_1^*A_1^*A_1A_1+\frac{2!}{1!\,1!}A_1^*A_2^*A_1A_2+\frac{2!}{0!\,2!}A_2^*A_2^*A_2A_2,
$$
in which the order of the operators in each product (again treating the half containing the $A_i^*$ separately from the half containing the $A_i$) *is* lexicographic.  That is, $A_2$ always occurs to the right of $A_1$ (and $A_2^*$ to the right of $A_1^*$).  We get from one side to the other by "combining like terms".  It is commutativity of the operators that allows us to do this.  The numerical coefficients in the sum on the right tell us how many "like terms" on the left contributed to each term on the right.

What needs to be shown is that these numerical coefficients have been chosen correctly, that is, that the number of functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$ in which $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$ occurs as the image of some $j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ exactly $\alpha_k$ times is given by $\frac{n!}{\alpha_1!\,\alpha_2!\,\ldots\,\alpha_d!}$.

**Added:** Since you ask about the case $d=3$, let's use that as an example.  If
$$
(X_1+X_2+X_3)^n=(X_1+X_2+X_3)(X_1+X_2+X_3)\ldots(X_1+X_2+X_3)\quad\text{($n$ factors)}
$$
is expanded, without assuming commutativity of the $X_i$ we get $3^n$ terms.  These terms are in one-to-one correspondence with the functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$.  So, for example, if $n=4$, one of the terms is $X_2X_3X_2X_3$.  It corresponds to the function $1\mapsto2$, $2\mapsto3$, $3\mapsto2$, $4\mapsto3$.

If we use commutativity, $X_2X_3X_2X_3$ equals $X_2^2X_3^2$.  But $X_2X_3X_2X_3$ is not the only term that equals $X_2^2X_3^2$: any term with two factors $X_2$ and two factors $X_3$ also equals $X_2^2X_3^2$.  In the notation of the proof you adapted, $\alpha_2=\alpha_3=2$ and $\alpha_1=\alpha_4=0$ for the term $X_2X_3X_2X_3$.  Furthermore, because of commutativity, $X_2X_3X_2X_3=\mathbf{X}^\alpha=X_1^0X_2^2X_3^2X_4^0=X_2^2X_3^2$.  So $X_2X_3X_2X_3$ is one of the terms on the left that contributes to the term on the right containing $X_2^2X_3^2$.  Other terms that contribute are other terms with $\alpha_2=\alpha_3=2$ and $\alpha_1=\alpha_4=0$ such as $X_2X_2X_3X_3$, $X_3X_2X_2X_3$, and so on.  There are six such terms in all since there are $6=\frac{4!}{2!\,2!}$ ways to arrange the factors of $X_2X_3X_2X_3$.

The main difference between this standard multinomial expansion and your application is that your left-hand side cannot be written as an $n$-fold product.  Instead, your left-hand side is defined directly in terms of the functions from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to $\{1,2,3\}$.  Most everything else works as before.  So one of the terms on the left will be $A_2^*A_3^*A_2^*A_3^*A_2A_3A_2A_3$.  It can be rearranged using commutativity to get $(A_2^*)^2(A_3^*)^2A_2^2A_3^2$.  There are again six terms in total on the left that contribute to $(A_2^*)^2(A_3^*)^2A_2^2A_3^2$.

**Second addition:** This is a response to the request in the comments for a completely written-out proof and for an explanation of where $\alpha_k$ is used in the proof.

Your proof is complete. The issue may be that the notation used is rather concise, and may require some "mathematical maturity" to decode. In your proof, $\alpha_k$ is used when you write "And because $X_iX_j=X_jX_i$ for all $i,j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ then $\mathbf{X}_g=\mathbf{X}^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d$ such that $|\alpha|=n$." To translate this to my example, the term $X_2X_3X_2X_3$ corresponds to the function $g$ defined by $g(1)=2$, $g(2)=3$, $g(3)=2$, $g(4)=3$. The statement $\alpha_2=\alpha_3=2$, $\alpha_1=\alpha_4=0$ in my answer follows from your definition of $\alpha_k$, since there are two elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $g(j)=2$ (namely $j=1$ and $j=3$), two elements such that $g(j)=3$ (namely $j=2$ and $j=4$), and no elements such that $g(j)=1$ or $g(j)=4$. So your statement that I quoted is correct: $$\mathbf{X}_g=X_{g(1)}X_{g(2)}X_{g(3)}X_{g(4)}=X_2X_3X_2X_3=X_2^2X_3^2=X_1^0X_2^2X_3^2X_4^0=X^{\alpha(1)}X^{\alpha(2)}X^{\alpha(3)}X^{\alpha(4)}=\mathbf{X}^\alpha.$$

I might suggest some changes in wording. In the line I quote from your proof, I would replace the phrase "for some $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d$ such that $|\alpha|=n$" with "for $\alpha$ as defined above, which satisfies $\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d$ and $|\alpha|=n$", and in the next line of your proof, I would replace "But for each $\alpha$" with "But for each $\alpha$ satisfying these conditions".

Comment: Thank you very much for this very good explanation. However please is the proof inspired from the answer in my question correct?

Comment: What you need to do is to map my explanation (in the "Added" section) to your proof.  So in your proof there is a "chosen $g$".  In my explanation I chose a particular $g$, $1\mapsto2$, $2\mapsto3$, $3\mapsto2$, $4\mapsto3$, as an example. The definition of $\alpha_k$ in your proof is equivalent to the one in my explanation. So my $\alpha_2$ is $2$, which is "the cardinality of the fiber of" $2$ for my particular $g$. Your statement $\mathbf{X}_g=\mathbf{X}^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbf{N}^d$ is simply the rearrangement of the factors of $\mathbf{X}_g$ in lexicographic order.

Comment: Finally, "the different ways to order $g(1),g(2),\ldots,g(n)$ for some chosen $g$" corresponds to the different ways to arrange the factors of $X_2X_3X_2X_3$ in my example. If my example makes sense to you, then your proof should also now make sense. The key step is the replacement of the sum over $g$ with the sum over $\alpha$, which can be done since each $g$ gives you an $\alpha$. That the same $\alpha$ corresponds to different $g$ necessitates the inclusion of the multinomial coefficient in the sum over $\alpha$.

Comment: I didn't think anything was wrong with the proof you gave. The goal of my answer was to provide meaning for the symbols in your proof.  Is there a particular part of the proof you're dissatisfied with?  If so, perhaps I could try to expand on that.  It occurs to me that the proof assumes knowledge of some standard combinatorics involving words with repeated letters and the use of multinomial coefficients.  But I don't know if that is the part you are unhappy with.

Comment: Looks fine to me.